# I want my money i used the recommended fees for my 3 transfers but we going on 36 hours and no confirmation

Tags: transactions, blockchain

i did use the suggested fee from block-chain and still nothing what do i do .........decentralized currency is awesome but who is responsible when shit hits the fan if my bank was to mess up and not get my transfer lost i could call the bank and be fixed right away now im out my funds for going to be 3 days and no end in sight b41a9804a2e131196717b550553804dad75baec2e43a4817e6b1ba7cb2a12895   8d5e0ebff08ffd3ce6c4c4224a56d4e2458623476a21cb3ab732e2817a278f0b            00afdc1da94fd08b79e084c0ce60c5c97647e55ec9e8cef9dcc85aa1a4f44532

Answer (score 1):

No one is responsible if your account gets hacked , your funds stolen or your transaction is stuck. Your problem is caused as currently the network has a backlog of 200,000 unconfirmed transactions.